# QListView: how to automatically scroll the view and keep current selection on correct items in view when removing items from the top

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list view with a custom model. The model allows me to add text to the bottom of the list (using 'addText(const QString&)') and to remove items from the top of the list (using 'removeItemsFromTop(int _iCount)').

What is the best way to add text to the view and keep the model size under some maximum (lets say 'MAX_LIST_SIZE'), while always maintaining the view (i.e. current selection and items in view should not change when items are removed).

The solution should preferably be a function that I can use wherever I'm using my custom model.

I have looked at indexAt(...), scrollTo(...), currentIndex(...) and setCurrentIndex(...) methods on QListView, but I can't figure out how to put all of this together.

So far I have (for auto scrolling the view)

```
// add items here ...

// cleanup
QModelIndex indexViewTop = listView->indexAt(QPoint(8, 8));
if (listModel->rowCount() > MAX_SIZE)
{
    int iRemoveCount = (listModel->rowCount() - MAX_SIZE) + MAX_SIZE/10;
    listModel->clearTextFromFront(iRemoveCount);
    listView->scrollTo(indexViewTop.sibling(indexViewTop.row() - iRemoveCount, 0), QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
}
```

This is supposed to scroll the list view as items are removed to keep the view consistent, but indexAt(...) always returns an invalid index.

For keeping the selection consistent I tried:

```
// add items her ...

// cleanup
if (listModel->rowCount() > MAX_SIZE)
{
  int iCurrentViewIndex = listView->currentIndex().row();
  int iRemoveCount = (listModel->rowCount() - MAX_SIZE) + MAX_SIZE/10;
  listModel->clearTextFromFront(iRemoveCount);
  listView->setCurrentIndex(listModel->index(iCurrentViewIndex - iRemoveCount, 0));
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm still stuck on the auto scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my current approach and it seems to work well:

```
void addTitlesToList(Model *model, QListView *view, std::vector<Object*> &items)
{
    QScrollBar *pVerticalScrollBar = view->verticalScrollBar();
    bool bScrolledToBottom = pVerticalScrollBar->value() == pVerticalScrollBar->maximum();
    QModelIndex indexViewTop = view->indexAt(QPoint(8, 8));

    // add to model
    model->pushItems(items);

    // cleanup if model gets too big
    if (model->rowCount() > model->maxListSize())
    {
        int iCurrentViewIndex = view->currentIndex().row();
        int iRemoveCount = (int)(model->rowCount() - model->maxListSize()) + (int)model->maxListSize()/10;
        model->removeItemsFromFront(iRemoveCount);

        // scrolls to maintain view on items
        if (bScrolledToBottom == false)
        {
            _pView->scrollTo(indexViewTop.sibling(indexViewTop.row() - iRemoveCount, 0), QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
        }

        // maintain selection
        if (iCurrentViewIndex >= iRemoveCount)
        {
            view->setCurrentIndex(_pModel->index(iCurrentViewIndex - iRemoveCount, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            view->setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex());
        }
    }

    // move scroll bar to keep new items in view (if scrolled to the bottom)
    if (bScrolledToBottom == true)
    {
        view->scrollToBottom();
    }
}
```

One issue I had with `indexAt(QPoint(...))` is that I was calling it after adding the items to the list, which seems to cause it to always return an invalid index. Calling indexAt before anything is added to the model seems to work.
I also added automatic 'scroll to bottom' if already there (i.e. the view either stays fixed on specific items or sticks to the latest items if scrolled all the way to the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

I did a queue-like table model implementation. I think it is similar for `QAbstractItemModel`. Best way would be to use `QQueue` to store data.

Now, this is a snipped for `QAbstractTableModel` (which is subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` so it should work; `mEvents` is `QQueue`):

```
// custom table for inserting events
void EventPreviewTableModel::insertEvent(const DeviceEvent &event) {
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
    mEvents.enqueue(event);
    endInsertRows();

    if (mEvents.size() > SIZE) {
      beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), mEvents.size(), mEvents.size());
      mEvents.dequeue();
      endRemoveRows();
    }
}
```

And also override `data()` and `rowCount()` to serve correct data.

For second part using `ItemIsSelected` flag for items you want to have selected is done through: `Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index)`

Comment: What would you use to keep the visible items in the view (i.e. Automatically scroll to keep the view fixed)?

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage They will be automatically retrieved with ```data()``` function which is ```override``` receiving ```QModelIndex```, so the data from ```QQueue``` will be returned (what is removed from ```QQueue``` will seem to be _deleted_).

Comment: I extended my answer with what I have tried so far. Hopefully it helps to show where I'm stuck. The model itself seems to work.